# How to use react-router-dom in a website with many many pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to make a blog website with react and react-router-dom. A blog website consists of 100s of pages. My question is that if i route all the blog pages, will my website become buggy and slow because it will have to load all components at once? Like the code below-

```
<Route exact path='/blog1' component={Blog1}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog2' component={Blog2}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog3' component={Blog3}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog4' component={Blog4}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog5' component={Blog5}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog6' component={Blog6}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog7' component={Blog7}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog8' component={Blog8}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog9' component={Blog9}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog10' component={Blog10}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog11' component={Blog11}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog12' component={Blog12}></Route>
<Route exact path='/blog13' component={Blog13}></Route>
```

Can some one tell me how can i do this thing:- when a user clicks on any link on my website, the website does not refresh but instead a component is requested from the server at that time and then the component  rendered just like what happens on Youtube.com . When someone clicks on any video thumbnail he wants to watch, the website is not refreshed but instead the component or page is loaded through the internet.

Comment: hey @Bipin,
I think you make a mistake, you shouldn't define every Blog posts as a separate component.
it has to one blog component with address of let's say `/blog` that refers to your blog list and then you could define a route like `/blog/:slug` to refer to every blog post.

Comment: please take a look at `useParam` example in react router page: 

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Comment: if you're confused yet, feel free to ask here

Comment: Hey thank you for your help but please see the question below the code. How do I load the component from the server without refreshing the page. Not "first loading all the components then rendering them when needed."

Comment: I think you have to just lazy load what you want and get blog info on top of API call on top of whatever @Mosijava has suggested. If you could take a minute to understand what he has said, there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using separate component for each blog post, you may create a single component for blog detail and use the data based on the parameters passed to that route.

Use a route like below and access id passed in to the route using `useParams` hook.

`<Route path="/blog/:id" component={BlogDetailComponent} />`

Comment: Ya i am understood. Now, please tell me how would i request the blog data from the node js server and how would i resolve the request :)

Comment: You can fetch your blog details from your blog detail component from `useEffect` hook. As said earlier, id of the blog post can be taken from `useParams` hook

Answer (score 0):

You can use a router hook useParam() to set dynamically your post according to blog ID

Pls see the official link for more details https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams